# Pause PHP script to prevent TimeOut

Tags: php, time, limit

I have a PHP scripts which creates a great number of files on my server, but unfortunately it runs too long. My Hosting Provider has a timelimit of 90 seconds, and the script would probably take up to an hour to get finished! Set_Time_Limit is blocked by the hosting provider and building in a sleep function doesn't really pause the script either. Is there another way to build in pauses so it won't quit on my after 90 seconds?

Thanks!
Sander

Comment: Have you thought about redesigning it to process small batches?

Comment: PHP supports [threads](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) so create files asynchronously. Oh, forgot to say not natively.

Comment: The script has to run by about 415 records of a table in my database and processing 2 records takes up about the 90 seconds. That would mean I have to create 207 different scripts. This is barely doable, but this is even one of the smaller ones, so unless you have a clever idea of doing this, it isn't really an option?

Comment: Try to use `cron` to start the script, usually it doesn't have a limited execution time.

Comment: @PLB yeh, sure, the shared host block `set_time_limit()` but they'll *definitely* have an experimental extension that provides a feature that makes it even easier to do stupid things that grind the server to a halt :-P

Comment: Your script takes too long to execute... and you think suspending it (making execution take *even longer*) is the solution? What exactly are you doing in the first place?

Comment: Unfortunately Cron Jobs are also not an option, loving my Provider so far.... :(

Comment: You could save the number of files created in a session and refresh the page each time a file's been created, and then start on the ID that the session is holding?

Comment: @DaveRandom Have not thought about that. ;) I hope soon it won't be experimental. :)

Answer (score 4):

I can see why you're getting frustrated with your host, but they do things like this for the good of their customers. If one process can take all the processing power, it would slow down all the other sites on the server.

If you *really* need that kind of processing for each record, then a shared host is not the right solution; you need a dedicated server.

However, my guess is that the real solution to your real problem is not to throw more processing power at it, but to fix program's performance. You haven't explained what you're doing that makes a single record take 45 seconds to process, but if it's taking that long, it had better be something seriously impressive. More likely, it just means there's plenty of room for improvement.

I'd suggest doing a bit of profiling to nail down what it is about your code that makes it run so slowly. With a bit of work, I would be willing to bet that you could get the speed figures down by at least an order of magnitude, possibly more.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was thinking when I read the question.

Answer (score 1):

"processing 2 records takes up about the 90 seconds"

Make it process one record at a time, increment a counter, refresh the page, and hit-up the next record to process :-)

Comment: or better yet, fix the program so that processing two records takes a more realistic figure like 0.09 seconds. 90 seconds for 2 records is off the scale. If you've got data that *really* needs that kind of processing, you'll already know that PHP on a shared host is the wrong solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.  You would have to break it into smaller pieces or run a background job using [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

or

There's another approach [here](http://symcbean.blogspot.in/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult without knowing more about your code, but I think you have to write the code so that the script is called multiple times.
Do have the possibility to run a cron job? The script could be run ever x min and take the nest y files in a queue.

Why would you make all these files in the first place? Does not sound like good idea..

Comment: I'm creating a large database of products, I want a seperate page on every subdomain with a list of results of a certain category. I have 1800 categories and 415 subdomains, I don't see how this could be done any easier? All the pages work with templates, so every page actually only holds two lines, the link to the template and the line that tells which category we're dealing with. 

Unfortunately I cannot execute Cron Jobs, also blocked :(

Comment: @user What about dynamic pages? So they'll be generated *when requested*? You can cache those too... Also, spam farm? （・ω・）

Comment: Our who business model revolves around Google indexation, that's why I'm not to keen on dynamic pages, I should've mentioned that. What do you mean by Spam Farm?

Comment: yes I would say your best bet is to serve the pages dynamically and cache them the first time they are seen.  That is by far the best solution for your problem!!  Google will still treat them the same as static pages.  In fact google's spider should cause them to be cached when it visits.

Comment: @user "Spam farm" is pretty much what you seem to be doing... And what does Google have to do with dynamic pages?

Comment: @deceze, I can't say I appreciate you calling my project a Spam Farm since it is anything far from that, but I'm not going into specific details. I was worried that Google wouldn't be able to index a page, that doesn't exist until it's created dynamically.

Comment: @user No offense, but if your business revolves around generating thousands of pages across many subdomains to be indexed by Google, that a) is pretty much the definition of Google Spam and b) means you should understand better how pages are actually being indexed.

Comment: @deceze, no offense but since you don't know exactly what I'm building and your imagination seems to be too limited to think of something that wouldn't be spam, but still involve a very big website, it's not really fair to call it spam.